# Cocos2d-js hangs on bootscreen when trying to go fullscreen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cocos2d-js

my cocos2d-js game hangs with "Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture" on the loader-screen" on mobile.

since it seems that cocos requests fullscreen withou me coding that explicitly: how can i prevent this from happening?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution hidden in the docs:

```
cc.view.enableAutoFullScreen(false);
```

edit:

that seems not to work on Chrome...
still getting:

Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.

Answer (score 1):

For fullscreen functionality in browser you can use https://github.com/bdougherty/BigScreen instead of cocos built in api (I've used this lib with my HTML5 games). It's only 1.4kb and works as it should

Because of security constraints going to full screen should be triggered by a user gesture, so you'll need a button for it (You may call it Start Game for example) which will trigger this click handler

```
 function fullscreenButtonClick() {
    if (BigScreen.enabled) {
        BigScreen.request(element, onEnter, onExit, onError);
        // You could also use .toggle(element, onEnter, onExit, onError)
    }
    else {
        // fallback for browsers that don't support full screen
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
However I just did not know how to disable the auto-fullscreen feature.
Have found it hidden in the docs :

cc.view.enableAutoFullScreen(false);

Comment: oh, see my other answer it seems not to work consistently